# MDF file in a shared folder on a different PC

Tags: sql-server, winforms, mdf

I have a small application that uses a local database (MDF file) when i run the application on my computer it works perfectly fine, when somebody else tries to open the application on their PC nothing happens(not even an error message). 
Both the application and database are located on a shared folder. Other applications that have been made and placed in that folder do work as intended. The only difference is that this application connects to a database, could this be the problem? if so, why and how can this be fixed?

The connection string used is the following:

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=O:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Database.mdf;Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
```

And yes i am aware this should be done using a server, but that is currently not available yet.

Comment: You'll have to make it available then - it's as easy as using the already installed SQL Server Express. LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express, which means you already have it installed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sadly i do not have the right to do it, the people who do are rather slow in the process... and i kinda need to be able to test it on multiple PC's :|

Comment: Which is already possible through SQL Server Express. Which is *already* installed, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use LocalDB *at all*. You simply *can't* use SQL Server as if it were an Access database

Comment: `when somebody else tries to open the application on their PC nothing happens(not even an error message).` the only way for this to happen would be to actively suppress error messages, eg with a `catch{}`. Any call to `SqlConnection.Open` with an invalid connection string will throw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have no Try/Catch in the code. he just logged in on my PC with his credentials and was able to open the application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos also (to my knowledge seeing i can't find it anywhere and did not install it myself) i don't have Microsoft SQL Server express installed. The Database file was made using Visual Studio. But to get to the point. it is not possible to use a MDF file on a shared network folder with 2 pc's?

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) : `Microsoft SQL Server Express LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers. It is available on SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.` and later on `You can also install LocalDB as part of Visual Studio.`

Comment: The point is that you can't open the same database from multiple *servers*. This has nothing to do with shared folders (unless it's a permission issue). LocalDB is still a separate server even if it's embedded in your application.

Comment: Shared folder permissions can cause issues even for a single client if the user account has no write permissions to the file or folder. That will still throw though, not fail silently. If anything, any client code that tried to use the connection after a silent `Open` failure would throw itself

Comment: If you have multiple users on multiple machines wanting to use your data, you should **REALLY** put the database on a **server** and use the proper SQL Server protocols and mechanisms - and not fiddle around with sharing a `.mdf` file on a drive..... that's a dev feature, which quickly turns into a huge kludge and nightmare - spare yourself those troubles! Use SQL Server as it's intended to be used - as a **server-based** product

Comment: @marc_s would personally love to, but not allowed (yet) to use (as in add databases and such) because the people in charge are a bit slow with handling such requests. So the reason (for testing purposes only) i did it on a shared folder is to test the account settings. Had to do it this time by letting somebody else log in on my PC, which is a pain so guess i am stuck waiting on those guys to finish up.